# Proof of $\lim_{s\to 1^+}\frac{\sum_p p^{-s}}{\ln(s-1)}=-1$

Tags: number-theory

I am looking for a proof of $$\lim_{s\to 1^+}\frac{\sum_p p^{-s}}{\ln(s-1)}=-1.$$
If the proof is too long, a direct reference is fine. Here the sum $\sum_p$ denotes the sum over all prime numbers.

EDIT: Perhaps this is one of the examples Mathematica does not help. I put in $s=1.0001$ and calculate

Sum[(Prime[n])^(-1.0001),{n,1,10000}]/Log(0.0001)

I get $-0.294043$. I even use smaller $s$, and larger upper bound for $n$, but the answer is far from $-1$. If you can get it to close to $-1$, please let me know how you do it.

Comment: It is difficult to do becuase for $s$ close to $1$ you get "almost" harmonic series. Note that harmonic series diverges very slowly, so for $s\approx 1$ respective series will converge slowly. You need to try [acceleration method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration)

Comment: Is there an asymptotic formula $\sum_p p^{-s}$ that we can use?

Comment: I don't know. I suggest you to start from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html)

Comment: PrimeZetaP[s] is the Mathematica function for $\sum_p p^{-s}$. Using that I get my limit approximation very close to $-1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Since](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)
$$
\lim\limits_{s\to 1^+}(s-1)\zeta(s)=1\tag{1}
$$
it is enough to show that
$$
\lim\limits_{s\to 1^+}\frac{\sum\limits_{p\in P} p^{-s}}{\log\zeta(s)}=1\tag{2}
$$
Using [Euler poduct formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Euler_product_formula) we get
$$
\log\zeta(s)
=\log\prod\limits_{p\in P}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}
=\sum\limits_{p\in P}\log(1-p^{-s})
=\sum\limits_{p\in P}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{p^{-sn}}{n}\\
=\sum\limits_{p\in P}p^{-s}+\sum\limits_{p\in P}\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{p^{-sn}}{n}\tag{3}
$$
We have the following bound
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sum\limits_{p\in P}\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{p^{-sn}}{n}\right|
&\leq\sum\limits_{p\in P}\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\left|\frac{1}{p^{sn}}\right|\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\sum\limits_{p\in P}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{|p^{sn}|}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p^{\Re(s)n}|p^{\Im(s)n}|}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p^{\Re(s)n}}\\
&\leq\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p^{n}}\\
&\leq\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{t^n}dt\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=1\\
\end{align}\tag{4}
$$
From $(1)$ we know that $\lim\limits_{s\to 1^+}\log\zeta(s)=\infty$, then from bound $(4)$ and equality $(3)$ it follows that $(2)$ holds. And now we are done!